# Question concerning Gödel's 'The consistency of the continuum hypothesis'

Tags: set-theory

The work referred to is Kurt Gödel's 'The consistency of the axiom of choice and of the generalized continuum hypothesis with the axioms of set theory', Annals of Mathematical Studies number 3, Princeton University Press, 8th printing.

There is a primitive predicate $\mathfrak{Cls}(A)$ meaning '$A$ is a class'. My question is, isn't everything a class, making $\mathfrak{Cls}$ redundant?  Compare -- some of the classes are sets and there is a primitive predicate $\mathfrak{M}(A)$ meaning '$A$ is a set', that I see the need for.

Comment: $\mathfrak{Cls}(A)$ probably means "$A$ is a proper class".

Comment: Haven't looked at the source, but it's worth noting that the collection of all classes satisfying a property might not be a class. Olivier's answer is almost surely the right one though.

Comment: @OlivierRoche $\mathfrak{Cls}(A)$ can't mean '$A$ is a proper class' because the first axiom says that every set is a $\mathfrak{Cls}$.

Comment: Maybe it's there to rule out urelements?

Comment: @Nagase That's plausible. Thank you.

Comment: Why are you reading Gödel's original paper?

Comment: @Nagase.  Actually, it's not plausible!  An axioms says two classes are equal if they have the same sets as elements.  If urelemente existed two different classes could be deemed equal.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Because of its historical importance.

Comment: The importance of the results, yes. But they are presented in a modern language in so many places. It's like reading Newton in order to learn calculus. Sure, you can do it, but there's much better options.

Comment: @AsafKaragila The question remains - what is the predicate Cls() **for**?  Gödel didn't introduce it by mistake!  The monograph has been read by numerous profession logicians.  Maybe for half a second they wondered what I'm wondering, but, being profession logicians, they then got the point.  In his references Gödel cites John Shepherdson.  Many years ago I was a student of Shepherdson.  Sadly it didn't occur to me then that I'd have this question now!

Answer (score 0):

Without access I cannot be certain.  Looking at what JSTOR has allowed, I am reminded of Goedel-Bernays or Von Neumann-Goedel-Bernays which uses a two-sorted logic so that one can speak of classes of sets where sets are classes that are elements of other classes.

Compare what you are reading with what is on Wikipedia as Von Neumann Bernays Goedel set theory.

Edit:

Found enough,

https://play.google.com/store/books/details/Consistency_of_the_Continuum_Hypothesis_AM_3?id=NVbQCwAAQBAJ

Hit free sample.  You may get the same first pages.

Upper case variables are class variables, lower case variables are set variables.

Group A, Axiom 1

"Cls(x)"

translates to "all sets are classes"

Group A, Axiom 2

"If X is an element of Y, then M(X)'

translates to "Every class that is an element of a class is a set"

Group A, Axiom 3 is the extensionality of classes.  Since only sets can be elements in this theory, its universal quantifier uses a lower case set variable.

Comment: _Why_ say all sets are classes?  Everything is a class.  There are no urelemente.

Comment: The logic is not two-sorted. There are only class variable.  $F(x)$ is just short for $(x)(\mathfrak{M}(x)\to F(x)$.

Comment: What I'm reading is the monograph where von Neumann-Bernays-Gödel is first defined.  Note also that the Wikipedia article is about a theory different from that in the monograph that I identify right at the start of my question.  W. is about the theory in Mendelson's text _Introduction to mathematical logic_.